# Delphi - 7: sharing resources across all units without loading several parameters in function

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Hi I would like to know how to share resources across all units, such as value of textbox so that I can access it easily without without the need of parameters in the functions. Say if I have a large number of values from different components and information fetched from database, difficult to put them as parameters in the function.

Is there a standard way of doing that?

Comment: Using parameters is far better. Global variables are usually a very bad idea. Just pass parameters. Then your code will be cohesive and decoupled.

Comment: In addition to what David said, use a layered approach (ie presentation layer(=GUI), data layer). Don't rely on the design time components, but create them at runtime and keep them in classes that use them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Delphi for almost 10 years. Sorry if my answer is wrong.

I think you can put all these value into one common unit, let's call it [XXInfoManager]

and then:

(1)the UI units can put value inputted by the user into the XXInfoManager unit,
by something like:

```
XXInfoManager.setXXValue(UserInput.text)
```

(2)the function units can get value from the XXInfoManager unit,
by something like:

```
x := XXInfoManager.getXXValue()
```

Using this pattern, all the common value are managed by a common module,
so there will be no dependece between the modules which use these value and the modules which product these value.
Instead, they all depend on the common XXInfoManager module.

Comment: What you describe is a Singleton pattern and while it would solve OP's immediate problem, it will guaranteed open a can of worms down the road. [Singletons are Pathological Liars](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)

Answer (score 0):

While global variables are usually a bad idea, public read-only *properties* of a global object are not. And they can have the advantage of better (simpler) documentation of each global data item (because all of that documentation is in one place) and of the functions which use it (because they don't require umpteen different parameters, each of which really needs to be documented for the function).

Define a global object (in a single common unit typically) with private fields (*Ffoo : string*) for the data items, and expose them via public read-only properties (*property foo: string read Ffoo*). Then you can reference these items via references like *MyGlobalObject.foo*.

If the private fields' values are not set from within the this common global unit, then you must take care that they cannot simply be set "from anywhere". In that case the private values might be set by calling public functions of the common global object so the properties' values must be set intentionally by calling something like *MyGlobalObject.SetNewFoo(bar)* and not simply by writing *MyGlobalObject.foo := bar*. You can even test a Sender parameter in such functions: *MyGlobalObject.SetNewFoo(bar, Sender)* so that they may only be called by one specific object.

But as with all global data, maintaining data integrity even with this approach requires some coding self discipline and begins to be dangerous in code that is worked on by more than one person. Just be sure to control how the global data values may be set (who may set them), otherwise you'll go merrily down the **global variable rabbit hole** and that should be avoided at all costs.

*I was going to post this as a comment but ran out of characters; hence the reason for posting as an answer.*